# Which affiliation to use when publishing, when invited professor at second university

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing, research

I am a PhD student at one university and an invited professor at a second, i.e. I do not have a permanent position in the second one. Now I need to indicate an affiliation in a journal paper but I do not know whether to indicate or not to indicate a university where I am an invited professor.

> > What’s the etiquette for the affiliation to indicate in such a case - to indicate both or only the first one?

Comment: If you like some of the answers more than the other ones you can accept it.

Comment: @Piotr Hajlasz I waited for possible different opinions to be written. Since after 4 hours there are three answers with some numbers of up-votes I accept the answer with higher up-vote rate. I cought the point of all three answers (of Igor, yours and Iosif).  Thanks to all for help and effort.

Comment: Yes, it is good to wait awhile before accepting answers, but to be clear you should accept the one (if any) that best answers your question, which is not necessarily the one with the most upvotes.

Comment: @Kimball I completely agree with you (+1)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you get support (financial and moral) from both places, you should list them both.

Answer (score 9):

**You can write:**

University XXX (your permanent address)

*Current address:*

University YYY (your current address)

If it happens that the paper is going to be published after you are back at your home university, then you can remove the current address (when you receive proofs for final corrections) and leave only the address of the home university. **However, you should put in the acknowledgements something like that:** (This is an example of an actual acknowledgement from a published paper)

*Final version was prepared when the last author was staying
at Mathematisches Institut der Universitat Bonn; he gratefully acknowledges the
generosity of Humboldt Foundation and hospitality of his colleagues from Bonn.*

Answer (score 6):

I think you should list the institutions that supported any substantial part of the research presented in your paper. As for your other affiliations, I think you may want to list some or all or none of them.

Comment: "some or all or none of them" -- perhaps you could describe when each of these options might be preferred?

Comment: @j.c. : I think, concerning institutions that did not provide relevant support for the particular paper in question, it is completely up to the person affiliated with them to decide which ones to list or not to list.

Comment: The question is not about acknowledgements, but affiliation.

Comment: @Kimball : The question was, not about affiliations per se, but about which affiliations to indicate/list in the paper. My suggestion was to list those affiliations that have to be acknowledged because of support provided concerning the paper, and list any other affiliations optionally, at the sole discretion of the author of the paper. However, to avoid possible technical ambiguity, I have now replaced "acknowledge" by "list".

Comment: I have never heard of institutions requiring you to list them as your affiliation address just because part of your work was done there or supported by them.  At least in my experience, these affiliations were primarily about listing your current/permanent addresses so people can find you.  (There have been other questions about this on this site)

Comment: @Kimball : I have never heard of institutions **requiring** listing them either. However, if an institution is listed in a publication, it does add to its visibility. So, I think the author should list them, if they indeed provided support for the research presented in the paper.